# First time Laravel facing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm following flynsarmys' laravel [tutorial](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-2/). Everything went well until the second part where I put the index for ProjectsController, when I tested to navigate to 15todo.app:8000/projects in browser the app throws NotFoundHttpException.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
// Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
Route::resource('projects.tasks', 'TasksController');

Route::bind('tasks', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Task::whereSlug($value)->first();
});
Route::bind('projects', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Project::whereSlug($value)->first();
});
```

ProjectsController.php

```
public function index()
{
    return view('projects.index');
}
```

I have googled and searched, but I still haven't find a clue of why this is happening. If I checked php artisan route:list it showed like this

```
$ php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                    | Name                   | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                      |                        | Closure                                         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | projects                               | projects.index         | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | projects/create                        | projects.create        | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create  |            |
```

What am I doing wrong? Help...

My dev env is homestead on windows. For the console I'm using Git Bash (MinGW). My 15todo.app:8000 is up and showing "Laravel 5" and random quotes about simplicity.

Comment: I had the same problem and it turns out I never enabled mod_rewrite on my server. However if you're using Homestead this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: does `15todo.app:8000` work?

Comment: Have you created a clinic index view? You're trying to return a view that may not exist.

Comment: @Digitlimit yes 15todo.app:8000 work

Comment: @Ben how do I create such view? You can give me links about it if its too long to write here. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code for your routes in your question

Comment: @brokekidweb has answered it below.

Comment: @Digitlimit added routes.php code

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting please comment out other routes and leave only this one 
`Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');` and try once more

Comment: @Digitlimit it still NotFoundHttpException, I'm looking for another tutorial website, it seems there is a step missing from this tutorial that I use.

Comment: I believe you are missing a point somewhere however laravel is simple. Setup a route, a controller and a view. You should read the documentation its better than most tutorials

Comment: Hmm yes, I think the tutorial is not very fool proof or beginner friendly despite the title "basic" :D

Comment: I don't know what happened. But this issue is gone after I experienced that I can't up my homestead. It is telling me that homestead cannot rename a folder inside Virtualbox VMs folder to homestead because there is already a folder with that name. So I deleted that folder and retried to up homestead. It succeeded and when I tried to access my controller, it works! I don't know how or why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the view. Save it in the `/app/resources/views/projects/` directory as `index.blade.php`. Reference the views documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views).

You can either create a new PHP/HTML file, but the best practice is to use the Blade template engine. For example:

```
    @extends('app')
        @section('content')
            <!-- your content here -->
            {{ 'escaped string' }}
            {!! 'non escaped <strong>string</strong>' !!}
        @endsection
    @stop
```

Read up a little bit more on the docs for the view, and check out this video [on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/3).

Comment: Yes sir I did add the view. Actually I read the second part of the tutorial thoroughly. Thanks for the answer anyway :)